# Ionic Text color change onclick

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm a beginner in Ionic 3.

I have a 4 text in same color, I'm trying to make when I click on the 4 text at for time I want to change color.

Example
I click on 1st text, then I want to change it black color
I click on text 2, then I want to change black color and 1st text  is  set a default color,

Please help me to fix this issue

```
    <div class="row">
      <div  class="col right-border">
        <div  text-center>
          <h2 class="main-one" >$ 2,300</h2> <p class="main-txt-home">Today's Revenue</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div  class="col bottom-border">
        <div text-center>
          <h2  class="main-one">$ 53,100</h2><p class="main-txt-home">Expected Revenue for this month</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div  class="col top-border">
        <div  text-center>
          <h2  class="main-one">12</h2><p class="main-txt-home"> Bookings taken today</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col left-border">
        <div  text-center>
          <h2  class="main-one">68%</h2><p class="main-txt-home">Total Monthly occupancy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your `chngcolor` function please ? Are you sure you're using Ionic 3 ? If yes, it shoud be `(click)` instead of `ng-click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ngClass] attribute to achieve this. This can be used to dynamically return the class name as per the last clicked text. The code will be something like below.

```
 <div class="row">
  <div  class="col right-border">
    <div  text-center [ngClass]="getTextColor('text1')" (click)="setSelectedText('text1')">
      <h2 class="main-one" >$ 2,300</h2> <p class="main-txt-home">Today's Revenue</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div  class="col bottom-border">
    <div text-center [ngClass]="getTextColor('text2')"  (click)="setSelectedText('text2')">
      <h2  class="main-one">$ 53,100</h2><p class="main-txt-home">Expected Revenue for this month</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div  class="col top-border">
    <div  text-center [ngClass]="getTextColor('text3')"  (click)="setSelectedText('text3')">
      <h2  class="main-one">12</h2><p class="main-txt-home"> Bookings taken today</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col left-border">
    <div  text-center>
      <h2  class="main-one">68%</h2><p class="main-txt-home">Total Monthly occupancy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In controller

```
 private selecteTextId :string;

 setSelectedText(textId:string) {
     this.selecteTextId = textId;
 }

 getTextColor(textId:string):string{
   return this.selecteTextId == textId? "highlight-color" : "";
 }
```

In scss file

```
.highlight-color {
  color:blue;
}
```

Comment: sir I'm not clear, can you please apply for a  my code

Comment: Are you overriding the color attribute in  scss class main-one and main-txt-home? Then that could be the reason.